# ResultObject: Error in getting output

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, python-2.6

I am getting "ResultObject: Error in getting output" message when I run the following code. I know it has something to do with "os.path.join" but can't figure out what.

```
import arcpy
import os

    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    CADInput = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    OutputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
    OutputGDB = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(OutputFolder, "AllPipes.gdb", "CURRENT")
    SpatialReference = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\Coordinate Systems\Projected Coordinate Systems\UTM\NAD 1983\NAD 1983 UTM Zone 17N.prj"
    OutputData = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(OutputGDB, "Data", SpatialReference)
    OutputCAD = arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(CADInput,OutputGDB,"CAD_Converted","1000",SpatialReference)
    OutputCADLocation = OutputCAD.getOutput(0)


    layerfld = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(os.path.join(OutputCADLocation,"Point"),"Layer")
    query = layerfld + "='WM-VALVE-ID'"
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(os.path.join(OutputCADLocation,"Point"),"Valve_lyr8",query)
    outfile = os.path.join(OutputData,"Valve")
    ValveFC = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("Valve_lyr8",outfile)
    arcpy.Delete_management("Valve_lyr8")
```

Answer (score 3):

The error here is that you are using the result of operations as values, instead of [Result Objects](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000000n000000). Any built-in tool returns a Result Object, not a string or path like you assume in your code. Assuming the output of [arcpy.CADToGeodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000001z000000) is the feature dataset created, you would save it by calling getOutput(0).

Based on your above example:

```
OutputCAD =  arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(CADInput,OutputGDB,"CAD_Converted","1000",SpatialReference)
OutputCADLocation = OutputCAD.getOutput(0)
```

I haven't played with CADToGeodatabase to know if it provides multiple results, but you can check if it has multiple outputs by reading the outputCount

```
print "The output consists of", OutputCAD.outputCount, "results"
```

Your os.path.join should stop complaining about joining a result object with a string after that.

Comment: Michalis, The output of arcpy.CADToGeodatabase is a featuredataset consisting of Annotation, Multipatch, Polygon, Point and Polyline feature classes. But the print command outputCAD.outputCount says only one result. I am trying to query out certain records from Point feature class. As you suggested, I used getOutput(0) but it is still giving me the same error. I have edited my code to reflect the change you suggested.

Comment: Sam, I would check the output to make sure it is the full name of the Geodatabase. AddFieldDelemeters excepts a Workspace. If your output is simply the FeatureDataset name, then AddFieldDelimeters will not function properly. You could try using os.path.join(OutputFolder, "AllPipes.gdb") to get the geodatabase workspace to pass through to AddFieldDelemeters.

Comment: Michalis, I am sorry if I confused you. The code results in all the feature classes I mentioned. I am not sure why print statement says only one result; may be its refering one feature dataset. And AddFieldDelimeters and rest of the code work fine if I hardcode the filepath. It is just not liking how I am using os.path.join.

Comment: @Sam, try to print out the result to verify that it is what you expect it to be. Just print OutputCad.getOutput(0) and see if that is the FeatureDataset name, the Geodatabase name, or something else.

Comment: As an alternative to using `os.path.join`, you could set the current workspace by setting [`arcpy.env.workspace`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w00000002000000). You may also consider [debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) in an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) such as [PyScripter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyScripter) to better understand what is actually happening in your code.

Comment: How do you use debugger in a code that requires input parameters (getparameterastext)? I used Pythonwin and pyscripter but not sure how to enter the parameters. I also tried setting path to debugger and right clicking the tool in ArcCatalog but without any success.